# HANA RLANG temporary file cannot open the connection

Tags: r, temporary-files, hana, arules

I'm using SAP HANA together with R. I use the cSPADE implementation in R and therefore load the data into a temporary file.
However until know it worked fine so far but now I getting an error. It seems to be some problem with the temporary file.

```
Could not execute 'CALL "BETA_SYSTEM"."run"()' in 15.741 seconds .
SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error:  [2048] "BETA_SYSTEM"."run": line 21 col 2 (at pos 821): [2048] (range 3): column store error:  [2048] "BETA_SYSTEM"."beta.procedures::selectSpadeData": line 33 col 4 (at pos 992): [2048] (range 3): column store error: search table error:  [34082] Execution of R script failed.;Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open the connection
stack trace:
2: file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
1: write.table(spade_data, file = file, sep = " ", row.names = FALSE,
       quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)


CREATE PROCEDURE BETA_SYSTEM.spadeR (  
  IN spade_data "SPADE_INPUT_T",  
  OUT result "SPADE_RESULT_T"  
)   
  LANGUAGE RLANG   
  AS                         
BEGIN  
  library(Matrix)  
  library(arules)  
  library(arulesSequences)  
  file <- tempfile()  
  write.table(spade_data, file = file, sep = " ", row.names=FALSE, quote = FALSE, col.names=FALSE)  
  df_trans <- read_baskets(file, info=c("sequenceID", "eventID", "SIZE"))  
  as(df_trans, "data.frame")  
  err_res <- tryCatch({  
   s_res <- cspade(df_trans, parameter = list(support = 0), control = list(verbose = TRUE))  
  }, warning= function(war) {  

  }, error=function(err) {  

  }, finally={  

  }  
  )  
  if(length(err_res) == 0){  
   result<-data.frame(sequence="EMPTY",support=0)  
  } else {  
   result <- as(s_res, "data.frame")  
  }   
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error stack indicates that there is a problem with accessing the file. This happens in the R processes spawned by RSERV. So it's outside SAP HANA and I would propose to check whether the R process with the same working directory can actually perform the file operation.

Maybe the file system is full or a access permission has been changed!?